# rails, devise sets cookie before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

In my test app, I can see cookie being set on hitting /sign_in path but not yet signing in. It's changed upon sign/log in, so auth works as expected. But I'd like to match requests via Nginx and cookie presence messes all up.

How do I disable cookie being set on one specific route?

Answer (score 1):

The cookie is a actually created by the Rack sessions middleware, not by Devise. In Rails the cookie simply contains a session identifier so that each visitor has a unique session.

Devise (or to be exact Warden) resets the session when you log in - thus a new cookie with a new session identifier is sent to the client.

> "How do I disable cookie being set on one specific route?"

Thats a bit harder due to the way Rails and Rack are built. Rack middleware is mounted when the server starts - not on a per request basis. So by the time the request hits the rails router (which is a Rack application) it has already passed through most of the middleware.

There are hacks like creating a custom piece of middleware that removes the cookie before it is sent:

```
class CookieFilter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    Rack::Utils.delete_cookie_header!(headers, '_app-name_session')
    [status, headers, body]
  end
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before ::ActionDispatch::Cookies, ::CookieFilter
```

However your milage may vary as this will break parts of rails that rely on session cookie such as flashes.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Comment: That's interesting. How then people do static landing pages with Rails as a upstream?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, you might to try asking another question on that exact topic. I would ask myself if it is not premature optimisation first though, there are usually much simpler steps (view fragment caching, SQL optimisation etc) that can yield some pretty big gains.